# Workbox ExpirationPlugin delete custom IndexedDB data

Tags: workbox

For each cache I am setting corresponding data to the cache into the IndexedDB.
Is it possible to delete this data too when the ExpirationPlugin deletes the cache?

Answer (score 0):

The [`deleteCacheAndMetadata()` method](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-expiration.ExpirationPlugin#deleteCacheAndMetadata) of an `ExpirationPlugin` instance sounds like what you're looking for.

Here's an explanation from the docs:

> This is a helper method that performs two operations:
>
> - Deletes all the underlying Cache instances associated with this plugin instance, by calling `caches.delete()` on your behalf.
> - Deletes the metadata from IndexedDB used to keep track of expiration details for each Cache instance.
>
> When using cache expiration, calling this method is preferable to
> calling `caches.delete()` directly, since this will ensure that the
> IndexedDB metadata is also cleanly removed and open IndexedDB
> instances are deleted.
>
> Note that if you're not using cache expiration for a given cache,
> calling `caches.delete()` and passing in the cache's name should be
> sufficient. There is no Workbox-specific method needed for cleanup in
> that case.

Comment: What I understand, it only clears the metadata created from the ExpirationPlugin itself, not my custom database that I created. And I don't know how I can overwrite it since it doesn't contains any information about which cache was deleted.

Comment: Oh, so you're talking about _cache entry_ deletion, not _cache_ deletion. Like, you want a callback when a specific entry in each cache is expired? That would be very difficult to do, since cache entries are deleted via an async function that is fired after a `fetch` event has been responded to, and in its current implementation, there's nothing waiting around to "listen" to those deletions. If you file a feature request at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/new we can figure out how feasible it would be to add that.